# How to exclude item from a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have this code in my `populateViewHolder`:

```
public void populateViewHolder(final CampaignHolder viewHolder, final Campaign campaign, final int position) {
            String k = getRef(position).getKey();
            ref.child(k).child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(getUid())) {
                       //Something...
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            //...Populating the viewholder...
```

I want to remove the item if `!dataSnapshot.hasChild(getUid())` is `true`, otherwise just keep on populating the ViewHolder normally. Note that I don't want to **remove the item from the database**, I only want it gone from the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. What method is available for doing this?

---

**Edit:** I am STILL looking for a solution for this problem as it has **not been fixed**. My solution is HIGHLY discouraged and very bad practice, and I have reconsidered using it myself.

Comment: Looks like next time I'll have to give a 400 rep bounty

Comment: Hii, i want to exclude specific records from firebase, like if date filed is <=1 hour.. do you have any clue? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice would be to use server side filtering:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

At the moment there is no way to filter your results client side with FirebaseUI (however I do believe it is planned to be implemented in the future):

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/135

Answer (score 1):

**Update: *This is extremely bad practice* and *very* glitchy. I *HIGHLY* discourage *ANYONE* to use this since it *will* make your RecyclerView very glitchy and will cause excess data loading, which is *NOT what your users want*.**

<s>I ended up making it manually as so:</s>

```
if(x)
   viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //itemView is a view provided by Android, no need to initiate it.
```

This says,  if `x` is `true`, get the row and set its visibility to `GONE`. This solved the problem for me. I will probably fork this on GitHub.

Comment: Don't set it to gone, set its height to 0 (and set the height to normal for the other elements)